# Sql update statment is not working in sql server azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am facing with one of the strange issue that update statement is not working on one of my table in sql server database on azure. Below is my query.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Applicant] 
SET [FirstName] = 'ABC' WHERE ([Id] = 1)
```

This query works fine for other tables. Also when I run above query it gives me message like

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Where there is only one row associate with id=1. ID is the primary key. What could be the issue.

Comment: is there a trigger on this table [dbo].[Applicant] ?

Comment: Yes there are three triggers written on this table.

Comment: you mentioned the query doesn't work on sql azure. did it not work or your question was related to 3 messages being returned

Comment: you already know the answer: check triggers!

Comment: I got answer. Just deleted these triggers and above statements work perfectly with values updated. Thanks guys!